# Setting a role mentioning permission

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I would like to create a role with JDA and set permissions so that only users with this role can mention this role. My current code is the following but everyone can mention this role.

```
    guild.createRole()
            .setColor(Color.GREEN)
            .setMentionable(true)
            .setName("MyRole")
            .setPermissions()
            .submit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord's permission system doesn't allow this. You can only give the role the [MESSAGE_MENTION_EVERYONE](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/Permission.html#MESSAGE_MENTION_EVERYONE) permission which allows them to mention any role. You cannot make a role that only role members can mention.